# How to get a continuous group of id

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I'd like to increment an id by group, for each variation of an attribute with only 2 values. like this :

```
1   banana
2   banana
3   egg
4   egg
5   banana
6   egg
7   egg
```

result wanted

```
id   food    grp
1   banana    1
2   banana    1
3   egg       2
4   egg       2
5   banana    3
6   egg       4
7   egg       4
```

I tried dense_rank() with window function but i only gives me 1 or 2 in grp column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions to solve this gaps and islands problem. Her is an approch using `lag()` and a window `count()`:

```sql
select id, food, count(*) filter(where food is distinct from lag_food) over(order by id) grp
from (
    select t.*, lag(food) over(order by id) lag_food
    from mytable t
) t
```

The logic is to compare each food to the value of the "previous" row, and count how many times it changed.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1b186d3241a527f78b311ed134b354ea)**:

```
id | food   | grp
-: | :----- | --:
 1 | banana |   1
 2 | banana |   1
 3 | egg    |   2
 4 | egg    |   2
 5 | banana |   3
 6 | egg    |   4
 7 | egg    |   4
```

Comment: Great ! i've never used filter : [https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS]